# How to change the color of folded lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Right now, it is a faint blueish, which is hard to see with my current settings. I tried searching for it manually in the JSON file but nothing so far. Is there any way to change the default color?

[image: image to code editor]

Comment: Completely aside, and more as a ‘kindness comment’ than a critique.  Perhaps consider following the code styling prescribed in [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), specifically in regard to function and variable names.  You’ll thank yourself later.

Comment: Will change it in the future @S3DEV

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the background of the folded up code line, you can set `editor.foldBackground` like so:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.foldBackground": "#ff0000"
  }
```

In the above sample code, I made it a bright red:

[image: example of bright red folded color background]

Alternatively, if you want to limit it to a specific theme, you can do the following:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": { //specify the theme
    "editor.foldBackground": "#ff0000"
    }
  }
```